# Since Google is deprecating fragments, what should we use instead?

Tags: android, fragment, deprecated

Google has placed Fragments on the "deprecated" list of features as of Oreo.  [Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) 
  Our project uses them but we are due for an interface redesign anyway (with a minimum target api of 5.0).  **What should we use instead**?
Usage Scenario:  Our project exclusively runs on tablets where the left 1/4 of the screen is a list of orders and the right side is a detailed view of the order ticket in question. Since there are fourteen ticket types, we swap the right side out with a different fragment depending on the ticket type you picked on the left, dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragments aren't deprecated, the implementation is being moved from the SDK to the support libraries (which are also being renamed).  Since you should have been using support library fragments anyway, it should be close to a no-op.  If you weren't, you'll need to move to support library fragments and possible support library activities, which should be straight forward although it will touch a lot of files.

Comment: what are they being renamed to?  or is that information not out there yet?

Comment: Fragment.  Its only the built into the sdk fragment class that's going away.  The support libraries themselves are becoming androidx

Comment: doesn't that imply that they are moving away from fragments then?

Comment: No.  They're getting rid of it in the main SDK because there's always been version specific problems.  Moving it only to the support libraries gets around that by making it a part of your app rather than a part of the phones framework, reducing the difficulty of patching bugs.  They're basically admitting it should never have been part of the framework but always should have been an add on library.  They're moving in that direction with a lot of stuff.

Comment: so support libraries get compiled into the app?  I was not aware of that.

Comment: Yes.  THey're separate pieces of software from the framework.  And by doing it that way, updates, fixes, and new features can be pushed without an OS upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one
android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: i know but if it's being deprecated that means they expect a different app interface to be used instead.  We were already using the support library so devices earlier than 5 could run it.

Comment: From google: Starting with Support Library release 26.0.0 (July 2017), the minimum supported API level across most support libraries has increased to Android 4.0 (API level 14) for most library packages.

Comment: sure.  But we didn't have any devices older than 4.  Currently the oldest tablet we use (we have 600) is running 5.1.